# Retrieving multiple values from a configuration file

Tags: python

I have a file with a configuration that looks something like:

```
settingA=3
settingB=6
settingC=12
settingD=5
#Item 1
item1_A=0
item1_B=2
item1_C=8
#Item 2
item2_A=1
item2_B=1
item2_C=9
#Item 3
item3_A=1
item3_B=4
item3_C=3
```

I want to extract some variables to perform some calculations.
If itemN's A variable is set then I want to include itemN's variables B and C in the calculation.
Given the example configuration file above the output I want to calculate is:

```
settingA + settingB * ((item2_B * item2_C) + (item3_B * item3_C))
3 + 6 * ((1 * 9) + (4 * 3))
=129
```

I have tried loading the entire file into a dictionary but then I do not know how to iterate through the dictionary values properly.
I can get the output I want but I have hard coded each setting/item variable:

```
def get_pair(line):
    key, sep, value = line.strip().partition("=")
    return key, value

with open("config.txt") as fd:    
    d = dict(get_pair(line) for line in fd)

settingA = int(d.get("settingA"))
settingB = int(d.get("settingB"))

item1_A = int(d.get("item1_A"))
item1_B = int(d.get("item1_B"))
item1_C = int(d.get("item1_C"))

item2_A = int(d.get("item2_A"))
item2_B = int(d.get("item2_B"))
item2_C = int(d.get("item2_C"))

item3_A = int(d.get("item3_A"))
item3_B = int(d.get("item3_B"))
item3_C = int(d.get("item3_C"))

item1_total = 0
if(item1_A == 1):
    item1_total = item1_B * item1_C

item2_total = 0
if(item2_A == 1):
    item2_total = item2_B * item2_C

item3_total = 0
if(item3_A == 1):
    item3_total = item3_B * item3_C

total = settingA + settingB * (item1_total + item2_total + item3_total)
print(total)
```

I am trying to turn the hard coded solution into a generic solution where there can be any number of items that I can iterate through.

Comment: Please add an example of the expected output.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where you are getting issue

Comment: Shouldn't the last three lines start with `item2` in that example?

Comment: Updated with expected output and corrected item2 variables.

Comment: Please add an [mcve] to your question. Without seeing your code, or at least an MCVE, it's difficult to answer your need here.

Comment: This looks like a data problem. Your config is not serving your code very well, so your code has to work very hard. Can you change the config? (JSON springs to mind)

Comment: @AdamSmith unfortunately it is an existing config file already in use. I am trying to calculate data consumption based on the set up in the config. I thought this would be a quick task but my python needs much improvement.

Comment: @LogicTom this will not be a quick task with this data structure. It's possible but *incredibly* brittle. You'll have to essentially write your own parser/lexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I alluded to in the comments, this is a very simple solve by changing your config. For instance, JSON:

```
# contents of config.json
{
    "settings": [3, 6, 12, 5],
    "items": [
        {"A": 0, "B": 2, "C": 8},
        {"A": 1, "B": 1, "C": 9},
        {"A": 1, "B": 4, "C": 3}
    ]
}
```

Then you can load the json in Python

```
import json

with open('path/to/config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

total = config['settings'][0]

scalar = sum(item['B'] * item['C'] for item in config['items'] if item['A'])
total += config['settings'][1] * scalar
```

---

Your comment seems to close the door on changing the config file, so instead your new job should be to parse the existing (bad) config to something more usable like the JSON above. Once done, an approach like the above should work well.

Comment: Thanks. The config would work all round much easier in JSON but this is a legacy embedded product - next version will definitely be JSON. I have other plans for making use of the config outside of the device so writing a parse to convert sounds like a worthwhile step.